# Pointers: '%s' expects argument of type char*, but argument has type 'int'

Tags: c, pointers

My print statement keeps throwing "warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 2 has type 'int'" However, I have checked over my function multiple times and do not see how strings[i] has type int.

```
char lineReversal(char ** stringPtr)
{
char * strings = *stringPtr;

for(int i = 873; i >=0 ; i--) {
    if(strings[i] == '\0'){
        break;
    }
    printf("%s", strings[i]); //warning thrown here
}

*stringPtr = strings;
return 0;
}
```

When the loop and print statement is in the main() function as opposed to in a separate function, it works just fine without error, so this is clearly an issue with my pointers. I am a beginner in C, so I may be missing something trivial, but I have done a good amount of research and am coming up dry.

Comment: Why wouldn't it throw an error?  You've defined strings as a `char *` and then you dereference it with `strings[i]`.  `strings[i]` isn't a `char *`, which is what `printf` requires in that spot with a `%s`.

Comment: `strings` is a `char *`, so `strings[i]` is a `char` (which is converted to `int` in the call to `printf()`).  You might be wanting to print `&strings[i]` or `strings + i`.  Your algorithm is dubious; you don't normally know what garbage comes after the first null byte in a string.